# Error de conexión mssql

Tags: javascript, sql-server, nodejs, express, mssql

Estoy tratando de establecer una conexión a mi base de datos usando la librería mssql de npm, sin embargo al tratar de establecer conexión me salta el siguiente error:

```
 ConnectionError: Failed to connect to PSTMDEDC02:1433 - 1088:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1994:

    at connectListener (C:\Users\pr\Documents\GitHub\apl_distri_reports_api\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70:17)
    at Connection.onConnect (C:\Users\pr\Documents\GitHub\apl_distri_reports_api\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:1725:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Connection.emit (C:\Users\pr\Documents\GitHub\apl_distri_reports_api\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:1868:18)
    at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\pr\Documents\GitHub\apl_distri_reports_api\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:2189:12)
    at C:\Users\pr\Documents\GitHub\apl_distri_reports_api\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:3169:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',

  originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to PSTMDEDC02:1433 - 1088:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1994:

      at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\pr\Documents\GitHub\apl_distri_reports_api\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:2189:28)
      at C:\Users\pr\Documents\GitHub\apl_distri_reports_api\node_modules\tedious\src\connection.ts:3169:25
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
    code: 'ESOCKET',
    isTransient: undefined
  }
}
```

Este es mi archivo de configuración para conectarme a la bd:

```
import { ConnectionPool, IProcedureResult, IResult, config } from 'mssql'
import { inputModel } from './models/inputModel'
import { outputModel } from './models/outputModel'

const createConfig = (): any => {
  const config = {
    database: process.env.DATA_PASTEUR?.toString() as string,
    server: process.env.DATA_PASTEUR_SERVER,
    password: process.env.DATA_PASTEUR_PW?.toString(),
    user: process.env.DATA_PASTEUR_USER,
    options: {
      enableArithAbort: true,
      trustServerCertificate: true,
      charset: 'utf8'
    }
  }
  return config
}

const executeQuery = async (query: string, inputs: inputModel[]): Promise<IResult<any>> => {
  const pool = new ConnectionPool(createConfig() as unknown as config)
  await pool.connect()
  const request = pool.request()

  inputs.forEach(({ name, type, value }) => {
    request.input(name, type, value)
  })

  const result = await request.query(query)
  return result
}

export const getData = async (columns: string, table: string, condition: string, inputs: inputModel[]): Promise<IResult<any>> => {
  const query = `SELECT ${columns} from ${table} ${condition}`
  return await executeQuery(query, inputs)
}

export const executeStoredProcedure = async (procedureName: string, inputs: inputModel[], outputs: outputModel[]): Promise<IProcedureResult<any> | undefined> => {
  try {
    const pool = new ConnectionPool(createConfig() as unknown as config)
    await pool.connect()
    const request = pool.request()

    inputs.forEach(({ name, type, value }) => {
      request.input(name, type, value)
    })

    outputs.forEach(({ name, type }) => {
      request.output(name, type)
    })

    const result = await request.execute(procedureName)
    await pool.close()
    return result
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return undefined
  }
}
```

Y así es como levanto el servidor

```
import config from 'dotenv'
import cors from 'cors'
import express from 'express'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import reportsRouters from './routers/salesReportsRoutes'
import { validarJWT } from './middlewares/validar-jwt'

const allowlist = ['whiteList']

const corsOptionsDelegate = function (req: any, callback: any): any {
  let corsOptions
  if (allowlist.includes(req.header('Origin'))) {
    corsOptions = { origin: true }
  } else {
    corsOptions = { origin: false }
  }
  callback(null, corsOptions)
}

config.config()
const app = express()

app.set('port', Number(process.env.PORT))

app.use(cors(corsOptionsDelegate))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(morgan('dev'))

app.get('/', validarJWT, (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'Api reports' })
})

app.use('/api/salesReports', reportsRouters)

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Server start on port ${app.get('port') as number}`)
})
```

Comment: Habría que revisar la configuración del servidor MSSQL. Tu código se está quejando porque le están pidiendo usar un algoritmo no soportado.

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61197859/5587982). El mensaje de error *`routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol`* hace pensar en un problema con el protocolo de conexión, debido quizá a problemas de versión de Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La librería mysql de npm hace años que no recibe soporte y tiene varios inconvenientes... Antes de buscar otra solución quizás probaría mysql2 (última actualización en npm hace 4 días).

Otra opción podría ser la siguiente:

A partir de la versión 12 de Node por defecto es requerido TLS 1.2, entonces si el servidor SQL no lo soporta devuelve ese error.

Una forma de resolverlo podría ser por flags en versiones anteriores, o actualmente podrías agregar  cryptoCredentialsDetails en options dentro del objeto del connect.

Ej:

```
mssql.connect({
    user: ...,
    password: ...,
    server: ...,
    database: ....,
    options: {
        cryptoCredentialsDetails: {
            minVersion: 'TLSv1'
        }
    }
});
```